# Sparc Solaris 2.6 will not boot

Tags: solaris, boot, sparc

I have a very old Sparc Solaris network that was working fine last week, but after a power outage none of the workstations will boot.

The network looks like this:
host A: solaris 2.6, shares /export/home to network by NFS
host B: solaris 8, runs NIS server.  Mounts /export/home/ by NFS.
host C: RHEL5, shares /share to network by NFS.  Mounts /export/home/ by NFS.

I figured that the main problem was host A, since you need the home directories available for the other workstations to boot(?).  Host A does not mount anything by NFS as far as I know.  However, this workstation will NOT boot.  The OBP bootup sequence looks like this:

```
Boot device <blah>
configuring network interface le0
Hostname <hostname>
check file system <everything ok>
check ufs filesystem <everything ok>
NIS domainname is <name>
starting router discovery
starting rpc services: rpcbind keyserv ypbind done
setting default interface for multicast: add net 224.0.0.0: gateway <hostname>
<HANGS at this point>
```

Is there some kind of debug mode so that I can get more detail as to why the workstation won't boot?  Is my network structure inherently susceptible to power outage?  Is there a way I can boot up to command line so I can at least turn off the NFS mounting?

Comment: There is a way to boot Solaris in verbose mode. And if the text scrolls by to quickly you can use Ctrl+S to pause it and Ctrl+Q to let it keep going.

Comment: At the OK prompt boot -s will allow you to boot to single user mode which may get you in, boot -a is interactive mode which may help you find out what's hanging.

Comment: How do I boot into verbose mode?  boot -v???

Comment: Ok, I booted with boot -v, unfortunately the last line of bootup text is the same: setting default interface for multicast: add net 224.0.0.0: gateway <hostname>

Comment: I tried boot -a, but the last line of bootup text is the same: setting default interface for multicast: add net 224.0.0.0: gateway <hostname>

Comment: Maybe this host is trying to mount something unavailable and getting stuck.  I will try boot -s and check out my vfstab file.

Answer (score 2):

This problem was due to a failure of a foreground NFS volume to mount, due to the NFS volume being unavailable.  To fix this I booted into single user mode (Thanks lain!) and modified vfstab so that it would not try to mount the volumes.  Then I continued boot and everything came up fine.  In the future I will use option bg (for baground mount) in vfstab, since the default is foreground which can cause boot problems.

Comment: You previously wrote "Host A does not mount anything by NFS as far as I know." So was that a false assumption ?